# Division algorithm on $\mathbb{Z}_n$ without comparison

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Suppose you want to divide over $\mathbb{Z}_n$. So for example, over $\mathbb{Z}_{256}$, you want to divide $123$ by $4$. One option would be to do repeated subtractions, but this needs comparison so you know when to stop. Also, it needs a lot of subtractions.

Is there a fast algorithm for that? The division must be like a computer does, with rounding for things like $1/2$. It can also be done in a greater ring. So for example, we can use $\mathbb{Z}_{2000}$ to do this stuff, and then reduce the result to $\mathbb{Z}_{256}$.

Comparison is not strictly prohibited but the lesser, the better. If none, it's much much better.

Comment: Well, $123=4\cdot30+3$ and this also holds modulo $256$. I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: I want to get the result 30. Repeated subtraction would be a way but it has too many subtractions and comparisons. Can you think of a better way? Maybe using some ring properties?

Comment: Can you explain your question more? Let's say you have an element $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and a positive integer $d \in \mathbb{N}$. Putting $a \in \{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$, is the answer you want to be outputted the nearest integer to $\frac{a}{d}$, where here division is occurring in the reals? And the only "operations" one is allowed to determine the answer are computations inside $\mathbb{Z}_n$? Am I right?

Comment: @mathworker21 the division is not on the reals, it's ok to discard the remainder, so we just want floor(a/d). Yes, we cannot use floating points, so we can multiply, add and subtract inside `\mathbb{Z}_n`

Comment: Are you trying to implement integer division? If so, in what context? Programming languages tend to have built in functions for that. Also, why no comparisons, is this related to branchless programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb Z_{256}$ is not a field, so there isn’t a unique answer:

$$123 ≡ 4⋅30 + 3 ≡ 4⋅94 + 3 ≡ 4⋅158 + 3 ≡ 4⋅222 + 3 \pmod{256}.$$

In general, there are $d = \gcd(b, n)$ distinct results for dividing $a$ by $b$ modulo $n$. To find them, first do an ordinary division of $a$ by $d$ in $\mathbb Z$:

$$a = dq + r, \quad 0 \le r < d.$$

Let $x$ be the [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $\frac bd$ modulo $\frac nd$. (Equivalently, we could have found $x$ from the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) when computing $d$ above: $bx + ny = d$.) Then for each $0 ≤ k < d$, we have

$$a ≡ b\left(xq + k\frac nd\right) + r \pmod n.$$